# Testing useState in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to test a call to a useState hook but its saying not called. 
I'm logging that they simulate event gets fired and my handler is called and the setting of the useState inside the handler gets fired but my spy is not working for some reason.

```
const setState = jest.fn();
const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
useStateSpy.mockImplementation(init => [init, setState]);

test('input change event with less than 3 characters', async () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComp {...props} />
  );
  const event = {
    target: { value: 'me' },
  };
  const input = MyComp.find('input');
  input.simulate('change', event);
  jest.runAllTimers();
  await expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

the setState is giving me warning.

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Comment: The state is an internal implementation detail of the component, you shouldn't be spying on the React API.

Comment: You’re testing the implementation while you should be testing the behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to test the sate change of a React function component.

Comment: And that's not the thing you should be testing. What *observable side effect* is there of the state change? Different rendered output? A call to a function you've passed as a prop?

Comment: I'm testing the value that its been changed to.

Comment: He is testing to see if his component calls setState when the input changes

Comment: Yes thanks Avin. I'm testing the value that state has been changed too.

Comment: @AvinKavish I can see what they're trying to do, I'm trying to understand *why*. Testing internal state leaves your tests too coupled to your current implementation and hinders refactoring. If they're just testing the state has changed so they know the state has changed, the question becomes: so what?

Comment: Again I'm testing the value the sate was changed to. So ignore toHaveBeenCalled(). I was just using that to see if it would even fire.

Comment: **Why?** If the rest of the world can't tell that the state has changed, what's the point of the state changing? If the rest of the world *can* tell, because e.g. the rendered output changes, then *test that*.

Comment: Hmmm.... there is a certain truth to it, but wouldn't that require mocking setState in the first place? To be able change the rendered output setState has to work. Oh are you saying provide the actual setState? That's fair enough

Comment: Ok jonrsharpe now I get you. So just test the rendered output of what the state does when it changes. Ok that makes sense, thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe In a perfect world it would nice to mock away setState and the rest of React to be honest. Now that would be the perfect Unit Test. Just you and your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stub your input onChange with 3 characters. This should run through your event code and update your state.

Then you need to assert your code returns the expected characters. React test there stuff, you don’t need to do it too!

Please provide your input code and event handler..

Comment: The input is just a regular change event that calls a handler function. Then in there I setState. Not much to show as its just <input onChange={handler}